# rails records push

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Controller.rb**

```
@payments = PaymentDetail.joins(:project)
```

in view file @payments.count is equal to 550

When I change my controller like this

```
@payments = PaymentDetail.joins(:project)
@payment_errors = PaymentError.joins(:project)
@payment_errors.each {|payment_error| @payments << payment_error}
```

Still in view file @payments.count is equal to 550 while it have to be (550+@payment_errors.count)

Why I can't push @payment_error records into the @payments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `PaymentError` data into `PaymentDetail` table which is wrong. If you need it in array use `to_a`.

You can do like this:

```
 @payments = PaymentDetail.joins(:project).to_a + PaymentError.joins(:project).to_a
```

To use `will_paginate` for arrays. Add this line in your controller:

```
 `require 'will_paginate/array'`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of lazy loading.

```
PaymentDetail.joins(:project)
```

This does not load payments immediately. Instead payments are loaded as soon as you start accessing them (in an `each` loop, for example). You can force loading by casting result to array. Try this:

```
@payments = PaymentDetail.joins(:project).to_a
@payment_errors = PaymentError.joins(:project).to_a
@payments += @payment_errors
```

Or, if you don't need `@payment_errors` as separate var:

```
@payments = PaymentDetail.joins(:project).to_a + PaymentError.joins(:project).to_a
```

Comment: But I want to use @payments with will_paginate gem so it has to be ActiveRecord::Relation not array.I wanna also order it.